# Yii2 relational query help: select only records which have related records

Tags: activerecord, yii2, relationship

I have two tables A and B with relationship "A has many B".
A may not have any B records.

I need to write a query, which would select ONLY those A records, which have related records in Bs. Records which do not have related B-records should be ignored. 
Using Yii2 active record I'm also trying to load all A records with eager loading related B records. So here is what I have:

```
Movies::find()->with('shows')->all();
```

How do I add the neccesary condition to filter out movies without shows?
How can I add any condition on movies which depends on shows data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use innerJoinWith instead with, such as:

```
Movies::find()->innerJoinWith(['shows'])->all();
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#innerJoinWith()-detail